# Align Bootstrap columns from right to left to support RTL language

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a form in arabic style. I have used a panel class. text field generally start from left side, but i want to design form from right to left.

```css
.heading {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #0D91A5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12 ">
  <center>
    <h2 class="heading"> Registration</h2>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-info" style="direction: rtl;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><strong class="strong"> تفاصيل طالب | Executive Details</strong></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class=".col-sm-5 .col-md-6" style="direction: rtl;">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 ">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-6">
                <input type="text" name="id_no" id="id_no" class="form-control" placeholder=" رقم| ID Number" tabindex="1">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-0">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="  اسم| Name " tabindex="1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is coding i am using class offset-6 for textfield start to right side but another textfiled with same grom starting from another line. i want box field in same line.

[image]

can anyone tell me which class i want to use? or can i change in bootsrap css file?

Comment: use pull right class to float a div in right side

Comment: It's working fine in a Plunkr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To design an RTL layout use [Bootstrap RTL](https://github.com/morteza):

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Add `bootstrap-rtl.css` (after `bootstrap.css` file) and it will override all the CSS properties that are related to rtl support.

Comment: i got the folder name 'bootstrap-rtl-master' can i direct copy this folder in css folder?

Comment: @SayedRizwanHashmi take the file `bootstrap-rtl.css` from the library **bootstrap-rtl-master\dist\css** and copy it to your css folder and reference the file from there in your code

Comment: yes its working :) Thank You very Much @Idan b brother